# Wrong date format displayed dd-MM-yyyy instead of dd/MM/yyyy

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am trying to display date in this format `dd/MM/yyyy`

Model addnotations

```
[DataType(DataType.Date)]
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
public DateTime Time {get;set;}
```

In view

```
@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Time)
```

instead I am getting date in format `dd-MM-yyyy`
I have also tried `dd.MM.yyyy` which works fine.Anything works fine except desired result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is correct format 
`[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd'/'MM'/'yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]`

Answer (score 0):

You may try this:-

```
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd'/'MM'/'yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
public DateTime myDate { get; set; }
```

then use it like:

```
@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Time)
```

Comment: @user1075940:- Updated my answer as well!! Does that help??

Comment: have you tried on different regions setting? for me stringformat(dd/MM/yyyy) was showing dd/MM/yyyy in singapore devices but dd-MM-yyyy in India devices. I cannot explain reason, if someone can, that will be helpful. I worked around it with a custom converter